# Trouble with pandas to_csv function

Tags: python, pandas

the data that i'm working with has a tab delimiter. My issue is that when i try to put it to a csv / text file (with pandas), it displays the results like this

```
Symbol  Description
OM0S.SI
sally
3LLS.SI
walley
```

I am trying to achieve a result of this (seperated by a tab)

```
Symbol  Description
OM0S.SI sally
3LLS.SI walley
```

Here is a cut of the code that I have

```
nd = df.values[i]
test = pd.DataFrame(data=nd, index=None, columns=None)
test.to_csv('SGX[Defunct]' + '.txt', mode='a', sep='\t', header=0, index=0)
```

I have a separator that says to delimit it by a tab, but it doesnt give me what i want..

Please advise.

Comment: can you post raw input data and code to create your df

Comment: why you do this? nd = df.values[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're always adding only one i row each time (which, probably, wouldn't be the most pythonic way to solve that), you should sent to pandas list of lists instead, like this:

```
nd = df.values[i]
test = pd.DataFrame(data=[nd], index=None, columns=None)
test.to_csv('SGX[Defunct]' + '.txt', mode='a', sep='\t', header=0, index=0)
```

Edit:
Also you could write it in one line:

```
df[i:i+1].to_csv('SGX[Defunct]' + '.txt', mode='a', sep='\t', header=0, index=0)
```

Where df[i:i+1] will create one i row dataframe slice.

Comment: This works. my error was that I should have placed it in `[nd]` instead. But yes. But I was wondering, what would be the more "pythonic" way that you mentioned that I should write my code?

Comment: You shouldn't work with output files line by line. Mostly that's uneffective.